# iPhone 4 traps max-width:480px media queries

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design, media-queries, iphone-4

An iPhone 4 with a resolution of **640×960** falls into media queries specified within:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px)
```

This media query is at the very *end* of my CSS stylesheet...

**Above** this query are those working great for iPad (1024) and Desktop, etc...

What am I missing??

I'd like the iPhone4 to respond to media queries specified earlier in the stylesheet, targetted as: **(max-width:640px)** instead, of course...

For the record, my viewport tag is currently:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused css px and display px. Which is understandable because they're both measured in px. Sigh.

From the point of view of css, a retina display is only 320px wide. However, it's pixel ratio is 2 meaning every 1px in css-land is really 2px on the display.

[Taken from here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/) you can use a different selector to identify retina displays :

```
@media 
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
  (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Comment: Will this query also target iPad and stuff like that (Retina in general)??  I'd really only want to target the iPhone4 (well, 640x960 mobiles)...

Comment: `@media (max-device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` is what I use...http://blog.robotwoods.com/2012/08/media-queries/